# Docker: How do I access my server's public IP from within a container?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, traefik

I'm running different apps as docker containers on a linux server. I'm able to access the docker containers just fine using SSL. The reverse proxy I'm using is `traefik` configured to proxy subdirectories instead of subdomains.

These are my containers:

**Application A** - accessible via `https://abc.xyz/a`

**Application B** - accessible via `https://abc.xyz/b`

Both applications are up and running and working correctly when accessing them from my browser.

Now I need to embed **Application B** in **Application A**. I know I could just use the container's internal IP (since they are on the same network), however, the embedded application must be accessible to **Application A** as well as to my local browser - so I need to use a publicly facing IP/URL.

The problem now is that I simply cannot access `https://abc.xyz/b` from **Application A**. All the below commands are executed inside the **Application A** docker container.

Ping is working:

```
$ ping abc.xyz
64 bytes from 150.150.150.150: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.204 ms
```

So DNS is working.

However `wget` shows:

```
$ wget https://abc.xyz/b
Connecting to abc.xyz (150.150.150.150)
(Nothing happens)
```

I simply cannot figure out where the problem is. Is it in `traefik` or is this a docker limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I found out that it wasn't related to `docker` or `traefik` at all. The host linux had a firewall enabled (`ufw`) that was blocking the requests from the docker containers, since it wasn't configured properly.

I now allowed access from the containers and it works.